# How to properly set up R workspace given the following instructions

Tags: python, r

Help here would be AMAZING

This is a specific question regarding using the following python and R libraries:

https://github.com/armbrustlab/popcycle/wiki/SeaFlow-data-analysis-tutorial

I am really struggling to follow the steps to get my R project running properly. I think I am just not setting things up properly... like initial downloads.

I download and setup the python files in the terminal of my R project and then am able to access the `library(popcycle)` in R. However, I get errors when trying to run the following codes:

I run:
`save.sfl(db, cruise, sfl.file=sfl.file)`
and I am told `In save.sfl(db, cruise, sfl.file = sfl.file) : Could not run seaflowpy`

I run:
`seaflowpy_filter(db, cruise, evt.dir, opp.dir, process.count=4, width=0.5, offset=0)`
and I am told `could not find function "seaflowpy_filter"`

I run:
`save.filter.params(db)`
and I am told `argument "filter.params" is missing, with no default`

Also, I checked and found that the python path being used in my R console is different to the one being used in my terminal... I tried writing `Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("/Users/<username>/anaconda2/bin/python", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))` but that didn't change the path in the console...

Here are the instructions I am struggling to do correctly, I think I need to do them in an environment maybe?:

```
First we need to satisfy some dependencies. Make sure Python 2.7 is installed with Anaconda. Then install the seaflowpy Python package:

git clone https://github.com/armbrustlab/seaflowpy
cd seaflowpy
python setup.py install
# To test your installation
python setup.py test
```

```
Now download and install the popcycle R library

git clone https://github.com/uwescience/popcycle
cd popcycle
# This will install popcycle and automatically run some tests
Rscript setup.R
```

Comment: Could you extract the steps from the instructions that are relevant to your question so that we don't have to click on the link and read the entire thing?

Comment: Great point! just specified

Comment: @SamanthaMiller I am basically unsure how to download these files in a way that I can access them in my  R console. IE do I need to set up a conda environment to install properly or something